# Okuma - How to open the Windows start menu

Tags: authentication, windows-xp, okuma

I need to get into the Windows interface (XP).
I have read that you can use Control-Cancel, However I don't see any Cancel button anywhere :)

This is a P200LA with the typical panel.

---

The purpose of this is to get to a file share that I understand is available in order to get data out of the machine.

However - I have also considered using THINC API + MTConnect + Kepware to get data out (if anyone has comments on that, please let me know - I'm not convinced I know where to start)

Thanks!

Comment: I realize this is an older question, but look into http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80667/internet-of-things as a possible place to start asking questions about MTConnect.

Comment: @tbm0115 Hey, it looks like they moved to beta: https://iot.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "cancel" button is the button with three diagonal lines in it.
It is actually the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key.

Looks like this: [image: Okuma OSP Escape Key]

Holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while pressing this key will pop up the Start menu.
The same is true on your desktop PC.

---

One way of "getting data out" could be to use Windows file sharing, which I think is what you're suggesting. Collecting information for a program like [Proficy Historian](http://www.ge-ip.com/products/proficy-historian/p2420) on the other hand is a different matter.

It's not clear from looking at that software if it supports [MT-Connect](http://www.okuma.com/mtconnect) or not. If it does, then the[MTConnect Agent](https://www.myokuma.com/okuma-mtconnect-agent) would be a quick and easy way to support the desired data-gathering.

If it doesn't, or if you're more concerned with supporting the maximum number of machines "out of the box", I'd recommend writing your own OPC client and machine data collection program using the THINC API version 1.9.1.0, and the Kepware OPC server you mentioned. You wouldn't need MT-Connect in that case, and it would give you lots of flexibility.

The THINC API is backwards-compatible so even if the program uses API version 1.9.1.0 for example, it will run on a machine that has the latest version (1.17.2.0) installed.

For more information about writing applications using the THINC-API, you can refer to the [Open API SDK](https://github.com/OkumaAmerica/Open-API-SDK).

Comment: Yes... I am used to OPC Data.  The data will be production event (start/running), production count (since it is a part, probably also a bit), downtime, downtime reason, cycle time, and waste (if recorded on the machine).

It will all be sent to a historian for collection. The historian typically consumes OPC data, which is why I was thinking of this method as opposed to file sharing where I would have to consume and convert.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott said, reaching the start menu is achieved by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>(the 3 diagonal lines button near the <kbd>BS</kbd> button).

The Okuma MTConnect agent is available for free on the Okuma AppStore at http://www.myokuma.com/okuma-mtconnect-agent and there are many commercially available software packages that interface with the standard MTConnect agent (like [5ME](http://www.5me.com/home/manufacturing_software_solutions/freedom_elog_production_planning_software.html) and [Memex](http://www.memex.ca/solution/machine-monitoring/))

Depending on the age of your machine (back to P100-II from 2004), you may or may not need an NC Software or THINC-API upgrade to use the MTConnect agent. These are also provided for free from Okuma but [depending on your local distributor](http://www.okuma.com/distributors), there may be a charge to send a technician to perform the upgrade. At time of this writing (Nov, 2014) Okuma is still recommending the NC-Software and API upgrade be performed by an experienced technician.